# Exercise 5.6 Kochan's Programming in C

Tags: c

I cannot get a functional program for this problem (exercise 5.6 in Kochan's "Programming in C" .  The goal is to have the program take an input number, such as 123, and output "one two three".

Right now, ive got two loops that turn out the number I want outputted (eq. in 2345) 2 would be the desired output.  I also want that multiple tracked and subtracted from the initial expression.  So 2345 would output 2, then loop around, and have 2000 subtracted from 2345.  The program is the supposed to evaluate 345, output 3, and subtract 300 etc.  Then I will worry about converting it to words.

After hours of working on this I am wondering if there is a fundamental flaw i am missing.

For reference, the next chapter is arrays.  The book has covered loops (for, while, decifion making if, else, switch)

the code ive got so far is below.  I am trying to make it loop and have been wrestling with it for days.  All ive got to show for it is the following code, which is admittedly much much cleaner than it was when i started.  The part shown below works, but when I try to loop it it fails.  Its gotten to the point where I am just trying everything, to no avail.  Again, I want the below to loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number, counter, output;

    printf ("Please input your number\n");
    scanf (" %i", &number);

    for (counter = 0; number > 9; counter = counter +1){
        number = number /10;
        output = number;
    }

    while (counter != 0){
        number = number * 10;
        counter = counter - 1;
    }

    printf ("%i     %i\n", number, output);

    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: It would seem to me if you want 2345 to output 2 and subtract 2000, retention of `number` would be beneficial, as it is used in said-subtraction calculation.

Comment: You can find the individual digits and then use the switch case statement....

Comment: Can you use `log10` function from `math.h`?

Comment: whozcraig - I agree.  I had been using a for statement like...    for (multiple = number; number > 9; number = multiple - number),  and maybe 60 variations of that.

Comment: iharob    no, just cause it hasnt been covered so far in the text.

Comment: What you are trying to do is if input is `123` output should be `one two three`? scan the input as a string and use switch to print each string from `zero-nine` just a thought

Comment: havent gottent there yet in the book.  there has to be a way to do it with available functions..

Comment: The **recursive approach** is the best for this kind of problem !!

Comment: did you cover functions/recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement the concept that you stated in the question  and here is **your code** with **some changes** to make it work ! Hope it helps !!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number, counter, output;
    //you need to create another variable to store the previous number
    // in order to be able to make the substraction
    int originalNumber;

    printf ("Please input your number\n");
    scanf (" %i", &number);

    while(number!=0)
    {
        originalNumber=number; // preserve the number in every loop
        for (counter = 0; number >= 10; counter = counter +1)
        {
            // we changed the condition in the for loop in order to keep 
            // only inside the number the left most digit

            number = number /10;

        }
        // the output will contain the left most digit in every loop
        output=number;

        while (counter > 0)
        {
            number = number * 10;
            counter = counter - 1;
        }
        // we get the new value by doing the substraction
        //  345=     2345        -   2000
        number =  originalNumber -  number;

        // print the new number for the next iteration
        // and the left most digit
        printf ("%i     %i  ", number, output);

        //print the output using letters
        switch(output)
        {
        case 0:
            printf("Zero \n");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("One \n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Two \n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Three \n");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Four \n");
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Five \n");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Six \n");
            break;
        case 7:
            printf("Seven \n");
            break;
        case 8:
            printf("Eight \n");
            break;
        case 9:
            printf("Nine \n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now everything becomes easy for printing each digit with letters via the `swich()` statement !!

You can change the format of `printf()` to get the desired output !!

Comment: well that is the winner.  still quite discouraging, i felt id punched in at least 60 variations of the above.  I think what I had wrong was not having the statement declaring the original number within the curly braces.   Instead I had it before the initial while loop.        Just in case anyone was wondering, switches have been covered and I did have the switch part ready to go once the above was funtional.   Id left it out as im trying to post concise questions, and it wasnt the troublesome part.  Thanks very much all.

Comment: Anytime ! and as far you reach the recursive topic you will find that  it is much more easy to solve this problem using that approach !! good luck ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the previously downvoted answer, which took advantage of string representation (not allowed). This answer first finds the highest digit, then extracts each digit. Not knowing the maximum power of 10 that can be represented on the target platform, I could have started with `mod` derived from `INT_MAX` and used leading-zero supression, but this seems easier and clearer. Although I see it is (coincidentally) similar to @iharob's answer, which was doubly downvoted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *numtext[10] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

int main() {
    int number=0, mod=1, digit;
    printf ("Please input your number: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &number) == 1) {
        if (number < 0) {
            number = -number;
            printf ("minus ");
        }
        while (mod <= number)
            mod *= 10;
        for (mod=mod/10; mod>=1; mod/=10) {
            digit = number / mod;
            printf ("%s ", numtext[digit]);
            number = number - digit * mod;
            }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Because OP's classes have not yet covered strings?

Comment: I didn't down-vote but array of pointers to OP who says doesn't know strings might be a bit more don't you think so? But this should be fine I think. Using switch might be good for OP i feel. (+1) for the approach

Comment: @iharob's (now deleted) answer took the `switch()` approach, but as OP says he wants output "one two three", strings have to be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't covered some advanced topics yet, I suggest the following. First reverse the number by using a loop and then print the digits one at a time by using a loop.

```
/* read number */
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);

/* reverse */
int m = 0, count = 0;
while(n)
{   m = (m * 10) + (n % 10);
    n = n / 10;
    count = count + 1;
}

/* print the digits */
while(count--)
{   int digit = m % 10;
    m = m / 10;

    switch(digit)
    {   case 0: printf("zero"); break;
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

This does not handle the case where the user enters the number `0` so you have to handle that separately (using an `if-stmt`). I'm using a count of digits because the number `n` could end in zeros in which case they'll be lost when the number is reversed so the count keeps the loop going even if that happens.

I did not test this code so try it and see if there is something to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to everyones input i was able to start over from scratch and come up with a different way to do this.  It correctly interprets zeroes, however it does have a problem when the numbers are larger (8 digits).  I suspect this problem is grounded in the conversion from type (float) to (int).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int counter;

float   number;
int number2;

number2 = 0;

printf ("Please Enter a number\n");
scanf (" %f", &number);

while (number > 0.00000001){
{for (counter = 0; number >1; counter++)
number = number/10;


for (; number < 1; counter--){
if (number< 0.1)
printf ("zero\n");
number = number*10;
number2 = (int)number;

}
number = (float)number - (float)number2;

switch(number2)
    {
    case 0:
        printf("Zero \n");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("One \n");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Two \n");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Three \n");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Four \n");
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("Five \n");
        break;
    case 6:
        printf("Six \n");
        break;
    case 7:
        printf("Seven \n");
        break;
    case 8:
        printf("Eight \n");
        break;
    case 9:
        printf("Nine \n");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 int main (void) 
 {
 int number, flipper, left_digit, pointer;

 printf("Number to Word Generator\n\n");
  printf("Enter a number (8-length max) and I will speak it for you!\n\n"); 
 printf ("Enter your number.\n\n");

 scanf ("%i", &number);
 printf ("\n");

 if ( number == 0)
           printf ("Zero");  

  // Set Specefic Loop Maximum Limit at 8 digits
  if ( number <=99999999 && number >= -99999999 ){
  // Set negative entries to absolute value
  if ( number < 0){
          number = -number;
          printf ("Negative ");
  }

  //Pointer Doubles as Loop counter and digit identifier 
  //Locates digits by using remainder calculation        
  for ( pointer=100000000 ; pointer !=1 ; pointer = pointer / 10){

     //Starting with max possible (8th) character, 
     //If statement focuses the pointer onto the proper digit length.
     //If 'number' variable length is less than required pointer
     //value, pointer is divided by 10 to check 7th digit, then
     //6th, and so on until proper length is found.  
     if (pointer <= (number*10)){
             //the remainder must be reduced to a single digit
             left_digit = (number % pointer)/(pointer/10);    


             switch (left_digit)
                    {
                    case 1:
                         printf ("One ");
                         break;
                    case 2:
                         printf ("Two ");
                         break;
                    case 3:
                         printf ("Three ");
                         break;          
                    case 4:
                         printf ("Four ");
                         break;
                    case 5:
                         printf ("Five ");
                         break;                            
                    case 6:
                         printf ("Six ");
                         break;
                    case 7:
                         printf ("Seven ");
                         break;
                    case 8:
                         printf ("Eight ");
                         break;
                    case 9:
                         printf ("Nine ");
                         break;
                    case 0:
                         printf ("Zero ");
                         break;

                    default:
                    printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
                    break;
             } 
      }
 }
 }
  else
     printf ("Number is not within range!!");


  getch();
    return 0;
}
```